# Let G be a group, H a finite, odd order, normal subgroup of G. Element in G of order 2?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Stuck on how to answer this group theory question

> Let $G$ be a group (not necessarily finite) and let $H$ be a normal
>   subgroup of $G$. Assume $H$ is finite and that $|H|$ is odd. Prove that if $aH$ is an element of order 2 in $G/H$, then there exists an element $a_1 \in G$ of order 2 with $aH = a_1H$

Not sure how to make any progress. I know that since $aH$ has order that $a^2H = H$ so there must exist some element $a_j$ = $a^2$ where $a_j \in H$ and that there exists some $a_i \in a^2H$ s.t. $a^2a = e$ where $e$ is the identity element of G, but I haven't been able to make any other progress or if this is even the correct approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be on the right track.  You know that $a^2\in H$, so the order $k$ of $a^2$ is odd.  Can you show that $a_1 = a^k$ has order $2$ and that $aH = a_1H$?

Comment: Thank you! I got it :)